# Understanding of code part in AngularJS/Ionic2

Tags: angular, ionic2

I'm currently trying to understand a semi-finished Ionic 2 Project.

I found this decleration:

```
login: {username?: string, password?: string} = {};
```

For me, it looks like an object "login", with the properties username and passwort. What's the meaning of the question marks behind the properties and what sense has this allocation with {}?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you googled this?

Comment: @Bas I tried, but didn't find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It defines a variable called `login`

The part after the `:` is for defining the structure of login, it has 2 properties, `username` and `password`. Both are **optional** (the ? - so could be `null` or `undefined`)

The `{ }` is initializing the login variable with an undefined `username` and undefined `password` (Probably so he can use it later on as `login.username` and `login.password` in an ngModel for example)

If he wasn't using the `?` it would result in an error `Property 'username' is missing in type '{}'` which would force him to rewrite his initialization to be

`login: {username: string, password: string} = { username: '', password: ''};`